# How to simplify sqrt expressions in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I'm using [`sympy`](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) v1.0 in a [Jupyter Notebook](http://jupyter.org/). I'm having trouble getting expression to simplify how I'd like. Here's a toy example; it does the same thing my more complicated expressions do...

```
import sympy
sympy.init_printing(use_latex='mathjax')
x, y = sympy.symbols("x, y", real=True, positive=True)
sympy.simplify(sqrt(2*x/y))
```

gives me...

[image: expression from sympy]

But I would prefer...

[image]

How can I get `sympy` to group things in this way? Ive tried some of the other `simplify` functions, but they all give me the same result. Or am I missing something else?

Comment: If you don't set x and y as real and positive, SymPy won't split them apart (because it's invalid to do so).

Comment: @asmeurer Thank you this does indeed help. It still pulls the 2 out, but that's easier to deal with. I found I can also improvise by squaring everything to check how it gathers everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "symbol trickery" for numbers that you want to behave like symbols and "vanilla symbols" when you don't want simplifications (as @asmeurer pointed out):

```
>>> _2,x,y = list(map(Symbol,'2xy'))
>>> sqrt(_2*x/y)
sqrt(2*x/y)
```

Comment: Thanks! This feels like a workaround too, but a bit more workable than the other answer, so I'll accept it. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you. And yes, it's just one of several ways to work around this issue.

Comment: For me, the assumption `positive=True` on the symbols still breaks out the terms of the `sqrt` Any solution for this?

Comment: Don't make the symbols positive or else use `evaluate=False` as in `sqrt(2*x, evaluate=False)`.

Answer (score 0):

`sympy` really wants to simplify by pulling terms out of `sqrt`, which makes sense. I think you have to do what you want manually, i.e., get the simplification you want without the `sqrt` call, and then fudge it using `Symbol` with a LaTex `\sqrt` wrap. For example:

```
from sympy import *
init_printing(use_latex='mathjax')

# Wanted to show this will work for slightly more complex expressions,
# but at the end it should still simplify to 2x/y
x, y = symbols("x, y", real=True, positive=True)
z = simplify((2*2*3*x)/(1*2*3*y))

Symbol("\sqrt{" + latex(z) + "}", real=True, positive=True) # Wrap the simplified fraction in \sqrt{}
```

This really isn't ideal, but I looked through the docs for about an hour, and just couldn't find support for what you want directly. The `sympy` library is more about actual symbolic manipulation, less about printing, so I can hardly blame them.

Comment: I appreciate your insight, but this feels too complicated. The suggestion of not specifying real, positive symbols helped me. Thank you anyway.